# How to add more query to elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
const searchParams = {
        index: "products", // Replace with your actual Elasticsearch index name
        body: {
          from: offset,
          size: limit,
          query: {
            bool: {
              should: [
                {
                  wildcard: {
                    name: `*${fullTextSearch}*`,
                  },
                },
                {
                  wildcard: {
                    code: `*${fullTextSearch}*`,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      };
 if (category) {
   //add and query ( category = category)
}
```

I want to add query category into this searchParams  if category != null

How to add more query to elasticsearch query?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
const searchParams = {
        index: "products", // Replace with your actual Elasticsearch index name
        body: {
          from: offset,
          size: limit,
          query: {
            bool: {
              filter: [],
              should: [
                {
                  wildcard: {
                    name: `*${fullTextSearch}*`,
                  },
                },
                {
                  wildcard: {
                    code: `*${fullTextSearch}*`,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      };
 }

 if (category) {
   searchParams.body.query.filter.push({'term': {'category': category}})
 }
```